# mailItem.PropertyChange stops firing

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I am implementing Custom Task Panes with E-Mail Messages in Outlook.
The core is taken from this link [MSDN (Walkthrough: Displaying Custom Task Panes with E-Mail Messages in Outlook)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb296010.aspx)

Handler for property change is added:

```
    void TaskPane_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Globals.Ribbons[inspector].ManageTaskPaneRibbon
.toggleButton1.Checked = taskPane.Visible;
...some code here...

                mailItem.PropertyChange += PropertyChangeHandler;
            }
```

PropertyChangeHandler checks is recipients have changed and does some heavy routine with posts and so on. But... If I add 10 recipients and start to remove them with backspace PropertyChangeHandler stops firing at some point.
No errors. Buttons on custom task pane work fine.

What is wrong?

Seems that either event is eaten or inspector is incorrect, but I cannot spot problem and find the solution.

I also think that it might be about "heavy load" when next event is fired before previous is completed, but this is a guess

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the Save method or save the message explicitly to make the [PropertyChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868530(v=office.15).aspx) event fired. Outlook caches values in the UI and doesn't propagate changes until the item is saved.

Also I'd suggest creating a log file (a regular text file) where you can write the debug statements. Thus, you will understand what happens in the code.

Comment: Consider using Outlook Form Regions instead of task panes. See [How to: Add a Form Region to an Outlook Add-in Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386177.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Outlook Form Region... I do not see even a way to dock it left!

Comment: This is not about "save". I have event fired 3,4,5 times and then nothing happens even if I have it saved.

Comment: Did you have a chance to create a log file? Is the source object disposed anywhere in the code?

Comment: Which source object are you talking about? inspector? taskPane? mailItem?